# Java SimpleDateFormat returns unexpected result

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to use SimpleDateFormat of Java to parse a String to date with the following code.

```
public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateString = "2011-02-28";

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

        System.out.println(dateFormat.parse(dateString));
    }
}
```

I was expecting some parse error. But interestingly, it prints the following String.

```
Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 IST 195
```

Couldn't reason it out. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` has parsed `2011` as *month* number 2011, because month (`MM`) is the first part of the date pattern.

If you add 2011 months to year 28, you get year 195.

2011 months is 167 years and 7 months. July is the 7th month. You specified 02 as the day, 28 as the year, 28 + 167 = 195, so `02 July 195` is correct.

Comment: +1 for explaining why output is: `Wed Jul 02 00:00:00 IST 195`

Answer (score 23):

By default, SimpleDateFormat is lenient, so to get it to fail, you need to do:

```
dateFormat.setLenient( false ) ;
```

before parsing the date.  You will then get the exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2011-02-28"
```

Comment: @RMT it doesn't answer the question. Nothing wrong with the content of the answer - quite useful info (thx @tim) - but the question was "why that output", not "how to fix"

Comment: Actually he wanted to know, "why there is that output instead of an exception". So the reason for this is, setLenient is set to true, instead of false. For a perfect answer you should stick both of your answers together! ;).

Comment: My actual question was answered by @Bohemian , but this one also gives very valuable information. So, +1 for this.

Answer (score 5):

Call `setLenient(false)` on the dateFormat. Then you'll get your parse exception, like this:

```
groovy:000> df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy")
===> java.text.SimpleDateFormat@ac880840
groovy:000> df.setLenient(false)
===> null
groovy:000> df.parse("2011-02-28")
ERROR java.text.ParseException:
Unparseable date: "2011-02-28"
        at java_text_DateFormat$parse.call (Unknown Source)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
```

Bohemian is right, if you don't set the lenient property then the JDK will bend over backwards making sense of the garbage it's given:

```
groovy:000> df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
===> java.text.SimpleDateFormat@ac880840
groovy:000> df.parse("13-01-2011")
===> Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2012
groovy:000> df.setLenient(false)
===> null
groovy:000> df.parse("13-01-2011")
ERROR java.text.ParseException:
Unparseable date: "13-01-2011"
        at java_text_DateFormat$parse.call (Unknown Source)
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
```

Comment: hes not asking how to fix it, he's asking why is prints that out and not a parse exception

Comment: @RMT: yes, I know, I edited my answer to acknowledge that, then changed it to answer his question.