# java SimpleDateFormat giving wrong result

Tags: java, scala, date, simpledateformat

I am using java.text.SimpleDateFormat in Scala to convert string to date.

```
val isdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

isdf.parse("01/22/2016") gives Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 UTC 2017
```

How to fix this ? Are there any alternative?

Comment: Are you asking why parsing the month 22 doesn't result in an error? Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899019/java-simpledateformat-returns-unexpected-result

Comment: 22nd month of 2016 = October 2017

Comment: check your format, you are passing month as 22. either change your parse parameter or simpledateformat

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have "22" in the month position.  The date format you set is day/month/year, but it looks like the date you sent is in the format month/day/year.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting is different between the dates. You have mixed the month and Day up in your statements. try this:

```
val isdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

goodluck with the code.